# Convert HttpPost to HttpGet

Tags: android, json, http-post, http-get

I have code below. I write it with httpPost, but i have to convert it to httpGet. Because the webservice that we use need HttpGet.
How can i convert it and use it properly.
Thkans in advance.

```
String nameValue = new String();
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutConnection = 6000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 6000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpPost httpget = new httpPost(
                "http://178.16.1.1:8080/Pets/REST/WebService/setUser");
        HttpResponse response;
        String result = null;
        try {

            HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username
                    .getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pasword
                    .getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username
                    .getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", pasword
                    .getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("county", username
                    .getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("adress", pasword
                    .getText().toString()));
            httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                    "UTF-8"));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpget, ctx);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(result);

                nameValue = (arr.get("error")).toString();

            }
            return nameValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

GET sends parameters in the URL `http://178.16.1.1:8080/Pets/REST/WebService/setUser?username=username&password=password` as stated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

So you should use `StringBuilder` like this:

```
String[] parameters = new String[]{"username", "password"};
String[] values = new String[]{"username", "password"};
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(
                    "http://178.16.1.1:8080/Pets/REST/WebService/setUser");
url.append('?');
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    url.append(parameters[i]+"="+values[i]+"&");
}
url.deleteCharAt(url.length());
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url.toString());
```

this will create `HTTP GET` call to the `URL`

```
http://178.16.1.1:8080/Pets/REST/WebService/setUser?username=username&password=password
```